# VSTS UnitTests not being executed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have configured an automated build which also includes execution of some unit tests.

[image: build definition]

But during the build, the tests are not being executed. I get this in the log instead

```
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7054776Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7066669Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7067115Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7067779Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7068326Z Version      : 2.3.27
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7068574Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7068935Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2018-03-24T20:07:21.7069393Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8705830Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8706020Z ========================================================
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8706781Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707012Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,**\*Tests*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707192Z Test filter criteria : null
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707360Z Search folder : D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707549Z Run settings file : D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707774Z Run in parallel : false
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8707933Z Run in isolation : false
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8708739Z Path to custom adapters : null
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8708899Z Other console options : null
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8709085Z Code coverage enabled : true
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8709383Z Rerun failed tests: false
2018-03-24T20:07:22.8709610Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2018-03-24T20:07:23.8073718Z ========================================================
2018-03-24T20:07:25.6690709Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @C:\Windows\TEMP\f6f63931-2f9e-11e8-9f91-fdd742f719d8.txt
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9335847Z Microsoft (R) Testausführungs-Befehlszeilentool Version 15.6.1
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9341454Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9341695Z 
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9378102Z vstest.console.exe 
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9379216Z "D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9379442Z "D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"

....

2018-03-24T20:07:25.9420090Z "D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9420222Z /EnableCodeCoverage
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9420328Z /logger:"trx"
2018-03-24T20:07:25.9420454Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s"
2018-03-24T20:07:26.2604012Z Die Testausführung wird gestartet, bitte warten...
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4694235Z Der Testlauf verwendet DLLs, die für das Framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 und die Plattform X86 erstellt wurden. Die folgenden DLLs sind nicht Teil der Ausführung: 
...
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4708861Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4709254Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4709625Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4710019Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" wurde für das Framework 1.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4710395Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" wurde für das Framework 5.0 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4710768Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4731784Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4732207Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4732585Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4732980Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 5.0 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4733377Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4733762Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4734894Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4735274Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4735895Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4736998Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" wurde für das Framework 5.0 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4737426Z "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" wurde für das Framework 4.5 und die Plattform AnyCPU erstellt.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4737706Z .Navigieren Sie zu http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409, um weitere Details zum Verwalten dieser Einstellungen zu erhalten.
2018-03-24T20:07:26.4737813Z 
2018-03-24T20:07:27.5711032Z 2,8997
2018-03-24T20:07:27.5818401Z Datensammler "Code Coverage" – Meldung: Cannot find CodeCoverage.exe..
2018-03-24T20:07:30.3279055Z In D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.BackgroundWorker\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\MyProject.Helpers.Test.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Helpers.Test\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\MyProject.Models.Tests.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\MyProject.WebUI.Tests.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI.Tests\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI\bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI\bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI\bin\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI\bin\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.WebUI\bin\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll ist kein Test verfügbar. Stellen Sie sicher, dass Testdiscoverer und -executor registriert und die Versionseinstellungen für Plattform und Framework richtig sind, und versuchen Sie es anschließend noch mal.
2018-03-24T20:07:30.4420114Z 
2018-03-24T20:07:30.4989936Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2018-03-24T20:07:30.6177455Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

When accessing the build server and running the tests manually in VS, they're all executed.

Comment: Does your test assembly match the pattern specified? Are you sure it's being built in the platform/configuration specified?

Comment: Hello @daniel, from my feeling I would answer both questions with yes; do you have an idea how to proof? The logfile states e.g. this

    2018-03-24T20:07:25.9391937Z "D:\VSTS-Agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.Models.Tests\bin\Release\MyProject.Models.Tests.dll"

So I assume they are found and compiled

Answer (score 2):

Replace the value in Test assemblies box like this (exclude unnecessary assemblies):

```
**\*Models.Tests.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

Comment: I've added `!**\*TestFramework*.dll` and `!**\*MSTestAdapter*.dll` as well since had got those assemblies in the log